# Posting attachments with Facebook Graph API using iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, attachment

I've been trying desperately to publish a message with an attachment to the current user's wall using Facebook's Graph API. I've been successful at publishing a POST object with an image but once I start getting into attachments, it won't work. It's as if it is not recognizing that property.

Here is my code sample:

```
NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"ATT NAME", @"name",
                            @"http://my.web.com", @"href",
                            @"ATT CAPTION", @"caption",
                            @"ATT DESC", @"description",
                            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"property 1", @"PROP1",
                             @"property 2", @"PROP2",
                             nil], @"properties"
                            nil];

NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"post", @"type",
                               @"MY MESSAGE", @"message",
                               attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                               nil];

[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

This will publish "MY MESSAGE" but nothing else. The reason why I truly need this attachment is because of the "properties" element.

Thanks so much in advance!

**Edit:** I just wanted to clarify that if I use the following dictionary for my params instead of the one above, it works perfectly fine. My issue is that I need to use the "properties" property of the "attachment" object for formatting purposes. Here is the dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"post", @"type",
                               @"http://my.web.com/pic.png", @"picture",
                               @"http://my.web.com", @"link",
                               postName, @"name",
                               postCaption, @"caption",
                               postDescription, @"description",
                               postMessage, @"message",
                               nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I found how to send properties together with my stream post. I discovered it by taking a look at the html in the actual Facebook Wall page. Turns out, the parameters for the POST object are considered the attachment so the only thing to be done is add the "properties" property directly to the POST parameters like this:

```
NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"property 1", @"PROP1",
                            @"property 2", @"PROP2",
                            nil];

NSString *propStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:properties];


NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"post", @"type",
                           @"http://my.web.com/pic.png", @"picture",
                           @"http://my.web.com", @"link",
                           postName, @"name",
                           postCaption, @"caption",
                           postDescription, @"description",
                           postMessage, @"message",
                           propStr, @"properties",
                           nil];

[_facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

And voila! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

To Publish FEED you have to use  "USERID/feed"

Eg:
 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"1231241/feed"
                     andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];

and regarding the Properties, i dont think their is any properties with name "properties" is available for feed APIs.

Check out here:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Comment: Hi Aby, first of all thanks for your response. I actually have been able to publish using "me". I have even published images using the basic parameters described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ This same page refers to "optional attachments" that I am guessing are the objects described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/ in which case they do have a property named "properties".

Comment: I wonder if this will be possible for mobile device.  Because this is a stream attachment, which is usually supported for the websites.  If i am not wrong you are working on the iPhone with FBConnect SDK.

Comment: So do you want to upload or attach?  What kind of media? music, flash or movie?

Comment: It's a hosted image. I have already tried the attachment with and without the image property and nothing really works. I wonder if "attachment" is the actual property name because I cannot find any examples for this particular case.

Comment: Do you want your POST to look like this Published feed?  Check out this link and let me know: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: Hi Aby, thanks. Yes, that is kind of what I want, and it works with dialogs, only that I am publishing without a dialog. If I don't use the "attachment" property and use only the POST object properties described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ it works. The issue for me is that I need the "properties" property for the attachment to format the text (i.e. properties are supposed to add line feeds) that I am submitting to the post.

Comment: Try this out:  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:         PUT LINK OF THE WEBSITE or IMAGE, @"link",LINK OF THE IMAGE, @"picture",NAME of the IMAGE, @"name",  DESCRIPTION OF THE APP OR IMAGE, @"description",nil];
    
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"12312312/feed"
                     andParams:params 
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];

Comment: @"12312312/feed", where PROFILE_ID = 12312312;

Comment: Hi Aby, I just posted an edit to the question because it was kind of long to put it in a comment. Thanks.