# Which all permissions are required to post data on FB wall in iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, permissions

I am stuck in a problem where I think everything goes well only the permission required to post the data on FB is not proper. I have gone through the FB docs but can get that `publish_stream` is the one required.

Here are the list of permissions I am using as of now. Kindly inform if any one of required is missing or not.

`@"read_stream", @"offline_access",@"email",@"publish_stream",@"user_birthday"`

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to post ?

Comment: Its just a string I am trying to post with a link

Comment: publish_stream is sufficient for posting link. Try to clean build and remove build folder from application and remove application from simulator as well. just to cross check visit  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ and check you are not missing any required parameters.

Comment: @jennis, you can post your comment as an answer. Its relevant and i would like to upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`publish_stream` is sufficient permission for posting link.**

Try to clean build and remove build folder from application and remove application from simulator as well. just to cross check visit [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api) and check you are not missing any required parameters.

You can also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568642/posting-attachments-with-facebook-graph-api-using-iphone-sdk) which has answer and accepted, somewhat(not exact) similar to your question but you may get some idea for your problem.